# IntelliJ Idea - Install JDK 1.8 on Mac

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.3 and need to use Scala Version 2.12 for a project. However, IntelliJ says that JDK 1.8 is required for Scala Version 2.12. My problem is that I cannot select/choose JDK 1.8. Hence How can I set/install JDK to 1.8?

Any help is heavily appreciated.

[image: Error Message]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) you can download the Java JDK 1.8. After installing it, it should appear as an option inside IntelliJ.

**UPDATE:**

Find `File -> Project structure` menu and go to `Project Settings -> Project` tab. If on `Project SDK` the `Java version 1.8 SDK` is not selected, change it and click `OK`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I followed your suggestions: and installed "jdk-8u161-macosx-x64.dmg". However, I still do only have the option 1.6 above but not 1.8. So nothing changed. What else can I do?

Comment: Have you restarted IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, I did again restart both IntelliJ and the whole System (Laptop).

Comment: Thanks again, yes that seems to somewhat yield to the correct menu but I still cannot choose JDK 1.8; I can only select 1.6. : ( However, I can either click on "New ..." or "Edit". Can you guide me through the process of how to add a New JDK?

Comment: You should select `New`, and find the path of the new version of your `Java 1.8 JDK`, which should be close to the path of the current one.

Comment: SOLVED! If I clicked on "New..." I just had to select "JDK", the window popped up where I was in folder "1.6.0.jdk" by default. Now, all I had to do was to change to the new folder "jdk1.8.0_161.jdk" folder, which is stored in the same folder as "1.6.0.jdk", namely in the "JavaVirtualMachines" folder.

Comment: FYI, Oracle is but one of several vendors providing installers or binaries for a Java 8 JDK. Other vendors include, off the top of my head: SAP, Pivotal, Microsoft, Adoptium (formerly AdoptOpenJDK), Azul Systems, BellSoft, Amazon, Red Hat/IBM, and possibly others.

Answer (score 4):

## In 2022, you can use just `brew`

```
brew install openjdk@8
```

and then add into Intellij IDEA as new SDK with the following path:

```
/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8
```

maybe you need to update `PATH` env:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:$PATH"
```

### …and for the future give a try to [`sdkman`](https://sdkman.io/), is better than `brew`

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

then open a **new shell** and try `list` to see what you could install ;-)

```
sdk list java
```

At time of writing you could use:

```
sdk install java 8.0.312-tem
```

Answer (score 0):

2023 on `Mac` chip only `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8` and then use in terminal `vim ~/.zshrc` with `export JAVAC_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/` inside that file.